# Error connecting to VPN within Docker container

Tags: docker

I have an Ubuntu docker container with `openvpn` installed, and a `config.ovpn` file.

I try doing: 
`openvpn --config config.ovpn`

and get the following error:

`ERROR: Cannot ioctl TUNSETIFF tun: Operation not permitted (errno=1)`

Some googling seems to suggest that this is because of not running with `sudo` but does `root` not already have `sudo` permissions? (For what it's worth - running `sudo openvpn` makes no difference).

Answer (score 2):

Adding `--privileged` flag to `docker run` solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply add the right capacity to the container by giving the `--cap-add NET_ADMIN` parameter to `docker run`.